# mysql returns empty rsult set when searching for a string containing asterik sign

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am not sure if the problem I have with the my search function in my system is really what I claimed in the title of this post but I am confused a little bit in this.
I have a search box that searched the database for the given words of characters. But there are some texts in some fields in the database that start with asterisk sign `*`. Searching for these stuff returns empty result set.
Please guide me for anything causing the problem. I really do appreciate that!

if `$kw` is `*` or starts with it, then I get no result records from the bellow query while I know there are alot of records for this sort of search value.

```
$this->db->select("p.code as pcode,c.category as category ,p.title as ptitle, c.code as ccode");
$this->db->from("promotions as p");
$this->db->join("promo_categories as c", "c.code = p.cat_code");
$this->db->like("p.other", $kw);
$records=$this->db->get();
```

Comment: The problem is in case the asterisk sign is at the beginning of the searched value!

Comment: try using $this->db->last_query() and see if that code is generating the query you want to